# ScrollTop can't scroll back down right away

Tags: jquery

On below I have the scrollTop working and it scrolls up. However I can't scroll back down unless I wait 10 or so seconds. When I inspect it there are multiple click events registered. How do I prevent this from happening? Tried ,return false; one, live, but no luck. Maybe just need a break from looking at it? Thanks for the suggestions.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
        /*  PROGRESS BAR  */
        if ($("div").hasClass("progress-content")) {
          if (($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height()) >= $(".progress-content").offset().top) {
            $('.progress-bar').each(function() {
              var getPercent = $(this).data('percent') / 100;
              var getProgressWrapWidth = $(this).width();
              var progressTotal = getPercent * getProgressWrapWidth;
              var animationLength = 1500;
              $(this).stop().animate({
                left: progressTotal
              }, animationLength);
            });
          }
        }

        /*  BACK TO TOP  */
        if ($(this).scrollTop() != 0) {
          $(".back-to-top").fadeIn();
        } else {
          $(".back-to-top").fadeOut();
        };

        /*  STICKY HEADER  */
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > stickyHeader) {
          $('.sticky-header .header-menu').addClass("sticky");
          $('.sticky-header .header .open.category-menu').addClass('closed');
        } else {
          $('.header-menu').removeClass("sticky");
          $('.header .open.category-menu').removeClass('closed');
        }

      });

      $(".back-to-top").click(function() {
        $("body, html").animate({
          scrollTop: 0
        }, 800);
      });
```